# What are the options for printing the consistency level used with the Cassandra Java driver?

Tags: spring, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Trying to print consistency level for datastax using JPA. We recently migrated to Spring version 2.7.0 version. As part of the migration process, the option for consistency was set at the driver level:

```
    return programmaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder -> programmaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder
            .withString(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_CONSISTENCY,  ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM.name())
            .withString(DefaultDriverOption.SESSION_LEAK_THRESHOLD, sessionThreshold)
            .build();
```

Tried setting the logging level at the root to trace but not able to see it set for any of the queries.

```
<root level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="defaultConsoleAppender" />
</root>
```

Logs

[image]

Before (3.10.x Cassandra Driver)

[image]

What are the other available options to print the consistency level at the query level. Any insights will be of great help.

Comment: sure that will be for great help.

Answer (score 2):

There are no APIs available today for achieving this with the Java driver.

There is no out-of-the-box option available short of extending the `RequestLogger` class and modifying it yourself. If you have ideas, you are welcome to [log a ticket](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA) and submit a PR which we are happy to review.

As a side note, I am interested in understanding what problem you are trying to solve. I am a little surprised that you need to log the consistency level used for queries since you have explicitly set a default. Either (a) you don't trust that the driver is honouring the configured consistency, or (b) you are facing another problem and you think logging will help you solve it. In any case, it would be better if you post a new question with details of the actual problem and we might be able to help you with it. Cheers!

Comment: There is a ongoing latency issue we are facing which querying the datastax clusters. The infra team (managing the clusters and configuration) wants to be sure that the client is sending the right consistency level for reads and writes (local quorum in this case). The prev driver (3.10.2) had the consistency level being printed when trace was turned on. This may not be a issue but something that can help us with audits.

Comment: Added a screenshot which had the consistency level in 3.10.x drivers.

Comment: "The infra team wants to be sure that the client is sending the right consistency level for reads and writes." The driver doesn't pick a random consistency level. It either uses (a) what you've configured, or (b) defaults to one. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will leave it to the infra team to be a better judge here by turning on the server logs for now. In case that’s not satisfactory, we will engage professional datastax help if needed!